# Sencha Touch - Can't load a local json file

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to use Sencha Touch 2 to load a local json file into a dataview.

When checking with Firebug - the file is being loaded by Sencha, but it is not being shown for some reason.

any ideas why?

Here is my code (the HTML is the basic Sencha html):

```
    Ext.require([
    'Ext.Panel',
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
    'Ext.Ajax'
]);

new Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    useLoadMask: true,
    launch: function () {

        Ext.regModel('City', {
           fields: [
            {name:'ID', type:'string'},
            {name:'Name', type:'string'}
           ]
        });

        var CitiesStore = new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'CitiesStore',
            model: 'City',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax', // ajax is for same domain, jsonp for cross-domain
                url: 'cities.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'cities'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel',{
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            scrollable: true,
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    html: 'Welcome to my app',
                    style: 'text-align: center;'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Search',
                    iconCls: 'search',
                    items: [
                        Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
                            store: 'CitiesStore',
                            itemConfig: {
                                tpl: '<h2>{Name}</h2>'
                            }
                        })
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    title: 'My App',
                    dock: 'top'
                }
            ]
        }).setActiveItem(1); // this is set for debugging only

    }
});
```

any the json is dead simple

```
{"cities":[{"ID":1,"Name":"new york"},{"ID":2,"Name":"las vegas"},{"ID":3,"Name":"los angeles"}]}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had issues with lists or dataviews not showing unless the parent container had a width set to a value or a layout set to 'fit'. In case it makes any difference, try:

```
    title: 'Search',
    iconCls: 'search',
    layout: 'fit',
```

Answer (score 0):

Having had a very quick glance... Few things - but firstly your reference to the store is incorrect.

In your DataView you should don't need the quotes:

```
store: CitiesStore,
```

Also you don't need the `new` keyword on the store as you're using Ext.Create.

This should get you a bit further at least.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Though it didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: remove the `itemConfig: {}` and leave just the `tpl..`

Comment: tried that... not helping :( I've changed it - tpl: '<h2>{Name}</h2>'

Answer (score 0):

are you using Firefox? Firefox and IE sometimes make problems when viewing
ply use Chrome or Safari.